# jQuery Mobile Navigation on a single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a single page jquery mobile application. This application has a single list

```
<ul id="channel_list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-theme="c">
  <li>Channel1</li>
  <li>Channel2</li>
</ul>
```

On click on any item in the list, I replace the list with new items

```
$('#channel_list li').remove();
$('#channel_list').append("<li>"+content+"</li>");
```

This app has 3-levels of navigation. How do I implement back and forward button functionality as URL remains the same?